# Exporting data from visual studio to CRM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm, vs-community-edition

I have a line of code written in C# from Visual Studio that gets the current time when a certain method is run. I was wondering how I would go about continually importing this data to CRM whenever the method is run.

For example if the method is first run at 3:05PM then again at 3:09PM. I want my CRM interface to be a table with a count on the left of 1 and 2 and the times on the right reading 3:05PM and 3:09PM.

So far, I've seen data importing of already populated data fields to CRM, but I haven't been able to find a dynamic solution that allows for this sort of importing. 
If you don't think this is possible, could you please suggest a work around. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a custom entity which would store the method name only, and use the out of the box CreatedOn field to keep track of when the method was called.

You could call that from wherever you need to store that information (plugin, workflow, web app,... etc).

So, say whenever you call method "myMethod()", just do a:

```
var myCustomLogEntityRecord = new Entity("new_mylogs");
myCustomLogEntityRecord.new_name = "myMethod";

service.Create(myCustomLogEntityRecord)
```

That's the idea.

You could use then CRM Dashboards to know how many times that method was called, and when, based on the CreatedOn field.